# Filter JPA collection association

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

I have a case were an Entity (Invoice) has a ManyToMany association to a set of other entities (BankOperations), however I want the elements of the associated collection filtered by some criteria:

```
class Invoice { 
  @ManyToMany 
  private Set<BankOperation> operations; 
}

class BankOperation {  

  @ManyToOne
  private Company company;

  @ManyToMany
  private Set<Invoice> invoices;
}
```

Given these 2 entities, if I use this JPQL:

```
select i from Invoice
```

Then I'll get all invoices in the db, and each invoice will contain all of the BankOperations associated with it.

I want to get all Invoices but include only the BankOperations that belong to a specific Company, can this be done with JPA? I know there are Filters for Hibernate, but that is Hibernate specific and there doesn't seem to be something similar in the JPA standard. Also, we are currently using EclipseLink as our JPA provider so this won't work for us.

Comment: `select i, bo from Invoice i join i.bankOperations bo where bo.company = :company`.

Comment: That won't work, because it'll return only those Invoices that contain BankOperations (there are Invoices without any BankOperations associated that I want to retrieve), I want to filter only the associated collection (with the given JPQL not only do I get fewer invoices, those Invoices contain ALL BankOperations, which is not something I want).

Comment: An Invoice will **always** contain all the operations of the invoice. That's what the association is for: contain all the operations of the invoice. The number of operations in this collection does not depend on the context. If you want a restricted number of these operations, you need a query, such as the one above, which searches for operations. You would need a left join and an on clause: `select i, bo from Invoice i left join i.bankOperations bo on bo.company = :company`.

Comment: I do get what you are saying, correct me if I'm wrong, but that query will get only invoices with BankOperations belonging to a single company, but every Invoice will have ALL associated BankOperations. Not what I want, Hibernate Filters do work here but are Hibernate specific. What we are doing right now is handle this logic at a different layer, before sending the data to the client (webservice, json) we filter the associated collection, but we wanted to know if this was the correct way to do it.

Comment: JOIN ON will not work with JPA 2.0